# Json and images

Tags: php, iphone, sql-server, json, touchjson

I've got a db on a server and want to get some data fro my iphone. I use TouchJson and everything works fine but I've got a little problem. I don't know how to download images. When I try to build and run the app the emulator just crashes. Got any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your JSON request provides a URL to the image then try:

```
NSString *path = @"http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: I never thought of using json to simply point to a url of an image. Thats clever insight

Answer (score 2):

Kevin already provided a solution for static images, but if you want to transmit dynamically generated images, you can use the same method with a data: URL.

You'd have to encode your image in Base64 (on the server), then on the client you just have to create a

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,the_base64_string_here">`

on the client (if using HTML5) or

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"data:image/png;base64,the_base64_string_here"]]` (if writing native code).

Answer (score -1):

When you get the path to the image from the db you can simply use `UIImage`s `-imageWithContentsOfFile:`.